# Ktor and remote tomcat deploying

Tags: tomcat, kotlin, ktor

Has someone successfully deployed a Ktor project in a remote Tomcat server?

I am working on a project, and when i try it in local deployment for testing everything is ok, but when i try to generate the .war and deploy on my remote tomcat server, i always get a 404 when trying to access the servlet.

The deployment seems to be ok, everything works without errors, bu i can't communicate with my servlet.

I have read a lot of guides, but all the people try it in local.

Regards

Comment: The problem seems to happen when the app is not the root application, and is in a folder inside webapps. When i try in local, is the root (and only) application, but not in the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Ktor people is improving now this functionality (https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/738), but is not implemented yet.
To solve this problem, you need to add the name of the FILEWAR.war, before of compile, on the routes:

```
route(FILEWAR) {
    get("/foo") { ...
```

Solution: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/487